# How can I delete/yank paste in vim and have it indent correctly? (not talking about :paste)

Tags: vim, auto-indent

Please note this is **NOT** related to `:paste` / `:nopaste` and the clipboard.  I'm talking about copying and pasting entirely within vim (`d`, `y`, `p`).

It is common to copy and paste a block of code from an outer block into an inner block.  Unfortunately, the indentation still is at the level of the outer block and I have to indent it afterwards.

What I want to do is to go from:

```
function foo() {
}
var bar;
var bazz;
```

to

```
function foo() {
  var bar;
  var bazz;
}
```

In vim what I normally do is:

1) go to the line

2) switch to visual mode

3) highlight the rows

4) `dd` to delete the lines

5) move the cursor up

6) `P` to paste

7) enter visual mode

8) highlight the rows

9) `>>` to indent the lines

I want it to automatically indent to the correct location.  It would be a much smoother workflow if I didn't need to re-highlight the rows and then indent them manually.  In other words, eliminate steps 7-9.

Anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily make this a keymap that does auto indenting as part of pasting.

For example,

```
nnoremap gp p`[v`]=
```

Breakdown:

```
p to paste text
`[v`] to selecte Pasted text
= to autoindent selected text
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this plugin.

https://github.com/sickill/vim-pasta

Looks like it does the same thing as ronakg mentioned above with some additional functionality.

Comment: It's a good plugin. I use it as well. But it's good to understand how stuff works. Cheers.